# Doubt in distributing $n$ different objects in $r$ different bins

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> My attempt - $n$ distinct objects in $r$ distinct bins

**One way would be $n^r$ ways.**

I have doubt in other method which I did in following way.

Say I choose $k_i~\forall i=1 \text{ to } r$ objects and place them in "$i^{th}$" bin.

Also $k_1+k_2+ \ldots + k_r=n$

Total number of ways of doing this = $\sum_{k_r=0}^n ...\sum_{k_2=0}^n\sum_{k_1=0}^n \binom{n}{k_1}\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}\binom{n-k_1-k_2}{k_3} ....\binom{n-k_1-k_2..-k_{r-1}}{k_r}$ (Please note that $\binom{n}{k} = nCk$)

The above expression by combinatorics seem fine to me. But I am not able to proceed from here.

Comment: We have $r$ choices for each of the $n$ objects, so there are $r^n$ ways to distribute $n$ distinct objects to $r$ distinct bins.  For the second part of your question, take a look at the [Multinomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: sir can u please tell me is my above expression correct?

Answer (score 1):

If we are placing $n$ distinct objects in $r$ distinct bins, then we have $r$ choices for where we place each of the $n$ objects, so there are $r^n$ possible distributions of the objects.

If we place $k_i$ objects in bin $i$, where $1 \leq i \leq r$, then 
$$k_1 + k_2 + k_3 + \ldots + k_r = n$$
The total number of ways we can distribute the $n$ objects in the $r$ bins is 
$$\sum_{k_1 + k_2 + k_3 + \ldots + k_r = n} \binom{n}{k_1}\binom{n - k_1}{k_2}\binom{n - k_1 - k_2}{k_3} \ldots \binom{n - k_1 - k_2 - \ldots - k_{r - 1}}{k_r}$$
where we sum over all $r$-tuples $(k_1, k_2, k_3, \ldots, k_r)$ of nonnegative integers with sum $n$.  The term 
$$\binom{n}{k_1}\binom{n - k_1}{k_2}\binom{n - k_1 - k_2}{k_3} \ldots \binom{n - k_1 - k_2 - \ldots - k_{r - 1}}{k_r}$$
can be expressed as the multinomial coefficient
$$\binom{n}{k_1, k_2, k_3, \ldots, k_r} = \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!\ldots k_r!}$$
which arises in the [Multinomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem), a generalization of the Binomial Theorem.  It states that
$$(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_r)^n = \sum_{k_1 + k_2 + k_3 + \ldots + k_r = n} \binom{n}{k_1, k_2, k_3, \ldots, k_r}\prod_{j = 1}^{r}x_j^{k_j}$$
If we set $x_j = 1$ for $1 \leq j \leq r$, we obtain
$$r^n = \sum_{k_1 + k_2 + k_3 + \ldots + k_r = n} \binom{n}{k_1, k_2, k_3, \ldots, k_r}$$
which is the number of ways of distributing $n$ distinct objects to $r$ distinct bins.